# Mocking Function with jest.mock in jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have mocked a function within my tests as

```
jest.mock('@lib/commons', () => ({
    callApi: () => Promise.resolve({id: 'value'}),
    validateSchema: () => true
}));
```

This works perfectly if I use it like this

```
jest.mock('@lib/commons', () => ({
  callApi: () => Promise.resolve({id: 'value'}),
  validateSchema: () => true
}));

it("test", async () => {
  // Test code
});
```

But the problem is I can not put the jest.mock inside `it`. Given I would want different result based on different scenarios, I would like this to work as a function. Any suggestions ?

Comment: When you mock inside the test it's not hoisted, the mock isn't there when the module you're testing gets imported. You'd have to move the import of that module into the tests too, see the examples in https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object. But note you don't really need to do this to have different responses in different tests - import the mocks into your test file and use the configuration methods they expose instead.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your mock you can use `jest.fn()` to create mocked functions. You can then use these functions to mock the results you need per test.

```
import * as C from '@lib/commons';

jest.mock('@lib/commons', () => ({
    callApi: jest.fn(),
    validateSchema: jest.fn()
}));

const callApi = C.callApi as jest.Mock;
const validateSchema = C.validateSchema as jest.Mock

it('test', async () => {
  callApi.mockResolvedValue({ id: 'otherValue' })
  validateSchema.mockReturnValue(false)
  // your actual test here
})
```

I believe `tsjest` has a [`mocked`](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/test-helpers/) helper that can make this a bit easier, but I have not used it myself.

Comment: Not working. This is giving me error `callApi.mockResolvedValue is not a function`

Comment: Could have to do with the way the library you use exports its methods. The method in general works because I've used it a lot in my projects. Try different ways to import. If no one else here has a solutions for you, I'm afraid you will have to use some search engines and read some blogs. The jest docs do not seem to cover it.